# how to bind data dynamically without pre-implementing the connection string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, connection-string

I have my sql data source but i want my program to dynamically bind it to the data source. 
I want my `dataAdapter` to bind to the data file by looking it through the project folder(source folder of the project/app). How can i dynamically produce a `ConnectionString` that will locate and bind itself to the `MyData.mdf` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your C# file to implement the code their to establish a connection string.

```
public SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings['"' + DatabaseName + '"' ].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (connectionString);
return con;
}
```

In the above mentioned statement you can dynamically call in the Database variable and run the GetConnection() method to create a connection to that particular database
In your web.config add your file location

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DynamicconnectionString" connectionString="Data Source = //your path for the DB file // "/>
</connectionStrings>
```